# Manim adding simple label updaters in loop

Tags: python, manim

I have two lists of `MObjects`: elements and labels.
I need to add an updater for every label to stay inside corresponding element.

So this is what I do:

```py
self.elements: list[Circle] = []
self.labels: list[Tex] = []

for i in range(5):
    angle = i * (360 / num_elements)
    point = self.circle.point_at_angle(angle*DEGREES)
            
    element = Circle(.75, WHITE, fill_opacity=1)
    element.move_to(point)
    self.elements.append(element)

    label = Tex(f'$\\mathbf{i+1}$', color=BLACK, font_size=70)
    label.move_to(point)
    label.add_updater(lambda mob: mob.move_to(element))

    self.labels.append(label)
```

The problem is that all labels stick to last element:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop makes use of a nested `lambda` function which is evaluated after the loop exits and points to the same circle element, which is the last one. You should update the code using the default argument so that it points to the correct one.

```py
label.add_updater(lambda mob, elem=element: mob.move_to(elem))  # Use default argument to capture the current value of the element
```

Reference: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, you saved me. I am a JS/TS programmer so this was kind of unexpected behaviour for me.

Comment: Glad it works! Your code is already easy to read and idiomatic, but If you want to learn more, I would recommend https://docs.python-guide.org/#writing-great-python-code